# 'withRouter' has been imported but still getting TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Here is my component code for adding a user.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import UserDataService from '../service/UserDataService';
import { withRouter} from 'react-router-dom';

class ListUsersComponent extends Component {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            users: [], 
            message: null
        }
        this.refreshUsers = this.refreshUsers.bind(this)
        this.deleteUserClicked = this.deleteUserClicked.bind(this)
        this.addUserClicked = this.addUserClicked.bind(this)
        this.createUser = this.createUser.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.refreshUsers()
    }

    refreshUsers() {
        UserDataService.retrieveAllUsers()
            .then(
                response => {
                    console.log(response)
                    this.setState({ users: response.data })
                }
            )
    }

    deleteUserClicked(id) {
        UserDataService.deleteUser(id)
            .then(
                response => {
                    this.setState({ message: `Delete of ${id} Successful` })
                    this.refreshUsers()
                }
            )
    }

    addUserClicked() {
        this.props.history.push(`/courses/-1`)
    }

    createUser(user) {
        UserDataService.addUser(user)
            .then(
                response => {
                    this.setState({ message: `User ${user.firstName} ${user.lastName} Successfully added`})
                    this.refreshUsers()
                }
            )
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <h3> All Users </h3>
                {this.state.message && <div class="alert alert-success">{this.state.message}</div>}
                <div className="container">
                    <table className="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Id</th>
                                <th>FirstName</th>
                                <th>LastName</th>
                                <th>Email</th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                                <th></th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            {
                                this.state.users.map(
                                    user =>
                                        <tr key={user.id} >
                                            <td>{user.id}</td>
                                            <td>{user.firstName}</td>
                                            <td>{user.lastName}</td>
                                            <td>{user.email}</td>
                                            <td>
                                                <img src={user.imagePath}></img>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button className="btn btn-warning" onClick={() => this.deleteUserClicked(user.id)}>Delete</button>
                                            </td>
                                            <td>
                                                <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={() => this.updateUserClicked(user.id)}>Update</button>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                )
                            }
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addUserClicked}>Add</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default ListUsersComponent
```

with simple button html

```
 <div className="row">
    <button className="btn btn-success" onClick={this.addUserClicked}>Add</button>
 </div>
```

But when I click the add button I get

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'push' of undefined
ListUsersComponent.addUserClicked
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:188:24
  185 | }
  186 | 
  187 | addUserClicked() {
> 188 |   this.props.history.push("/user/-1");
      |                      ^  189 | }
```

What am i missing here? Im pretty sure all my version are current. Ive posted all the code for ListUsersComponent as requested.  I have to type some more info because I have too much code now.  Any other needs to help assess my issue

Here is my controller as requested

```
    private UserRepository repo;

    @GetMapping("/users")
    public Iterable<User> getAllUsers() {
        return repo.findAll();
    }

    @GetMapping("/user/{id}")
    public User getUser(@PathVariable Long id) {
        Optional<User> user = repo.findById(id);
        if (user == null) {
            ResponseEntity.notFound().build();
            return null;
        }

        ResponseEntity.noContent().build();
        return user.get();
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the entire code of `ListUsersComponent ` ?

Comment: I updated the ListUserComponent code above to show all of it

Comment: Can you share the Route related code also, For Eg: <Route path component /> from your project

Answer (score 2):

`withRouter` is a higher order component, and it doesn't work by just importing it.

You actually need to wrap your component in `withRouter` for it to have access to `this.props.history`:

```
export default withRouter(ListUsersComponent);
```

You also need to wrap `App` with `Router`:

```
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

Comment: making this change gave me this error
```Error: Invariant failed: You should not use <withRouter(ListUsersComponent) /> outside a <Router>```

Comment: can you share your index.js file as well? looks like you haven't wrapped `Router` around your root component

Comment: import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();

Comment: I edited my answer, you will probably have to add `history` to your dependencies

Answer (score 0):

[Read Docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/withRouter)

> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest 's match via the withRouter higher-order component. withRouter will pass updated match, location, and history props to the wrapped component whenever it renders.

for the props to be available in the component, in addition to importing the function, you must call `withRouter(Component)`

in your case,

```
export default withRouter(ListUsersComponent);
```